# Where is / why is there no log for normal user systemd services?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to learn basic systemd usage and I've run into a confusing issue with user service units.

When running ordinary services with **systemctl start some.service** I can find the full log for this service (including what it has printed to stdout / stderr, as I understand it) by running **sudo journalctl --unit some.service**.

Consider the example servicefile **chatty.service**:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo "test from chatty.service"
```

When I place this service file in **~/.config/systemd/user/chatty.service** and run it with **systemctl --user start chatty.service** I cannot find its output sent to stdout in journalctl, neither with plain **journalctl** nor with **journalctl --user**. I only get the following output in both:

```
Jan 15 19:16:52 qbd-x230-suse.site systemd[1168]: Starting chatty.service...
Jan 15 19:16:52 qbd-x230-suse.site systemd[1168]: Started chatty.service.
```

And **journalctl --unit chatty.service** does not return anything at all (with or without --user makes no difference).

While if I move the same service file to **/etc/systemd/system** and run it with **sudo systemd start chatty.service** I then get the following output when I run **sudo journalctl --unit chatty.service**:

```
Jan 15 19:28:08 qbd-x230-suse.site systemd[1]: Starting chatty.service...
Jan 15 19:28:08 qbd-x230-suse.site systemd[1]: Started chatty.service.
Jan 15 19:28:08 qbd-x230-suse.site echo[27098]: test from chatty.service
```

It seems like the user service unit isn't as well integrated somehow, is this expected, am I missing something or is it a bug?

I am running openSUSE 13.1 x86-64, with systemd 208 (default install).

Comment: Same systemd 208 here on Arch Linux. You can use `journalctl --user --user-unit chatty` to get those start/stop messages from systemd, but not what the echo process outputs, at least in my case. You can get the echoed message with `journalctl --user` or use some other filter.

Answer (score 39):

Use `--user-unit` option, and in your case...

```
journalctl --user-unit chatty
```

Comment: Are you getting the "test from chatty.service" stdout message in the log output as well, or just the "Starting chatty.service..." and "Started chatty.service." messages?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the output from the process as well (i.e. the "test from chatty.service" message).

Comment: That is what I was expecting as well, but I don't see it here. May I ask what operating system (with version) you are running?

Comment: Arch Linux 3.13.7-1. systemd version 212.

Comment: I see the output in the main journalctl now. But when I try running `journalctl --user` I get `No journal files were found.` And the `journalctl --user-unit chatty` didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps Googling your error might help you out. I found this post on the Arch boards that seems to be relevant: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1335223

Comment: The intuitive thing would be `--user -u`, but no...

Answer (score 15):

Necroposting, but I faced and resolved the same issue today. Most probably `journalctl --user-unit chatty` didn't work for you because you run it from root. However, per `man journalctl`, `--user-unit` filters log entries not only by `_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=`, but also by `_UID=`, and there is no `chatty` service with root's uid, so no entries are found.

It's likely that you also have tried to run `journalctl --user-unit chatty` from your usual user, but got `No journal files were found`. This happens because (and *All users are granted access to their private per-user journals* from `man journalctl` can be confusing here) in 2018 on my Debian 9 journalctl still is not persistent by default (`Storage=auto` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, and `/var/log/journal/` doesn't exist), and in non-persistent mode `journald` doesn't support splitting logs, so all logs end up in single place in `/run/log/journal` despite the fact that splitting is turned on by default -- see `SplitMode` in `man journald.conf`. Enabling persistency fixes this.

TL;DR: enable persistency by putting `Storage=persistent` to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and reloading journald with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald`.

Alternatively, search with `sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=chatty.service`

Some more details are at
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-October/037554.html

Comment: Thank you. I was getting `No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.` with a confusing "hint" about setting permissions, but I should not have to set permissions because I am trying to access user logs, not system logs. Your fix worked. Many thanks.

Comment: This really helped: `sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=chatty.service`.

Comment: All i'm getting are logs about whether the service started or failed, but not output from the program itself. I see the program's output in the system journal but can't find a way to filter only this output.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me, there is no output :( (working on ubuntu 10)

Answer (score 7):

[Until systemd v230](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1621), you had to use the less intuitive `--user-unit` flag to view the logs for your user's unit:

```
journalctl --user-unit chatty
```

Since systemd v230, you can now combine the `--user` and `--unit` flags as you'd expect:

```
journalctl --user --unit chatty
```

The `--user --unit` syntax is supported since Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I'm not sur the "--user --unit" feature works on v230 ...  running v232 here, and this feature doesn't work